# Can i get USB 3.0 out of SATA II

Tags: usb, sata, usb-3, lga775

I was wondering if this is worth it. I have an old PC, and wanted to add USB 3.0 to it. The only PCIE I had is now using a wifi card, so I was wondering about using a SATA to USB 3.0 hub or something like that, but not sure if the speed difference will be worth it. The motherboard is an old [Asus P5KPL-AM EPU](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/P5KPLAM_EPU/specifications/)

Comment: You have 4 pcie slots, are they all full?

Comment: "SATA to USB 3.0 hub or something like that" - there is nothing "like that", SATA host controller has no commons with USB host controller, and no conversion is possible. These are totally different hardware devices.

Comment: Use a USB wifi adapter instead and leave the PCIe slot for USB 3.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

USB 3.0 is 5Gbit/sec.  I think it is possible depending on the USB chipset that the 5Gbit/sec is divided amongst all ports instead of per-port.

SATA II is 3Gbit/sec, and since it's technically a port and not a bus, the device connected to the SATA port has all that bandwidth to itself.

If this is a mechanical hard drive it's probably not getting much past 1Gbit/sec unless it's a hybrid0 drive with cache flash.

So you'll be fine.

If you're looking to install a USB 3.0 PCIe card for additional ports, do your homework if you plan to connect multiple SATA II devices to it.

---

If you really meant "Can I connect something to a motherboard SATA port to convert it to USB 3.0" - the answer is no.